# How to Append two different hash map on a particular node without replacing other in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to append two different hash map pairs on a particular node one with key value both being String and other String and Array List. But problem is Later one is replacing first one in Fire base database. what should i do? I cant use push() all the time.[Link of my code. Please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JKWG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you generate a unique random key. This can be done using [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) method.

> As we know, in the case of HashMap, it replaces the old value with the new one.

Don't forget to use `updatechildren()` method, and not `setValue()` method directly on the refrence when you want to update data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: For every child of a node i cant use push() method,I think it is not a good approach also i am creating child at a run time so there is no need of update children() for obvious reasons. Please see the code what i want to achieve. It will give you better idea.

Comment: It's a very good approach to use `push()` method. I kindly recomand you using `updatechildren()` method.

Comment: Suppose If a node has 10 children with key value pair , do we have to push every child? Although i know that if both (key-value) are strings we can use single hash map for all child, But here situation is different.

Comment: You cannot use in Firebase two different types on the same reference. That's not possible, once to use: `HashMap<String, String>` and second `HashMap<String, ArrayList>`. You need to use a single type, which is the first one -> `HashMap<String, String>`. Remeber that Firebase is structured as pair, of key and value and every node is an object which can be updaed either using a pojo class, or either using a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 1 `Map<String, Object>` instead of 2 different ones.
then you put all the data in that single map, string, arraylist